# Android SSL Handshake Failed when connecting to a web service using HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, boringssl

My Android app connects to a web service on my server. Everything worked fine yesterday, but today I got the error.

I didn't make any changes to the web service, nor to the app. I suspect it's something wrong with my server, but don't know where to start.

I tested it on both Android 5 and Android 6 devices.

Here is the error:

```
HTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-3) [1136,1136] HTTP Error (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException): Handshake failed
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:396)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(URLConnection.java:543)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:315)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getContentLength(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:146)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:159)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.access$1200(TiHTTPClient.java:85)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1207)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        ... 20 more
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:            ... 20 more
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xaef13100: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x9defc240:0x00000001)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:            at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:            ... 19 more
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xaef13100: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x9defc240:0x00000001)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:750 0xab1e350f:0x00000000)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:        ... 19 more
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xaef13100: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0x9defc240:0x00000001)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:750 0xab1e350f:0x00000000)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    ... 19 more
```

Any pointer is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just check your certificates validity expired. or suppose If you are used self signed certificate in your application.but, server side using authorized certificate means, this type of error may come.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if you have problems with your certificate
You can find more info here http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa

[image]